What is the generic way to put different number of variables into text?
I am trying to make a trait and item system that gives player stat with high roll and low roll.
I am using scriptable object for all the item and trait data including descriptions. Right now, for the description text, I just add a placeholder word for each number.
e.g., player takes "placeholder" more damage and deals "placeholder" more damage.(two variable) The trait class then has a list of two number that I will use to replace those "placeholder" word.
e.g., player receives less "placeholder" crit damage, deals "placeholder" more damage, and has "placeholder" more crit chance.(three variable)
I use String.Split() and iterate through the list to find each "placeholder" word, then replace them with each variable value.
I was trying string interpolation, but different traits and items have different number of variables to replace with, and I find that hard to use in my situation.
Is there a proper generic way to do this? or is my current solution ok?

try something like int  high = 100; int low = 0; Debug.Log($"I want to test {high} and {low} numbers");

you don't need a generic way to do that, but just use OOP-mechanics, which is: a Player has an amount of live (probably a number), he/she has a Name (usually a string), and deals some Damage (again a number). If you have these properties you can concatenate them e.g. using string-interpolation.

@BugFinder string interpolation works for one specific text, say I have two items with 2 modifiers and 10 modifiers, can I use one function for that?

you can use functions or whatever inside the {}

The "Placeholder" approach is correct. It can be better called "Replacement Variables". Decide a common syntax to identify the replacement variables. You can use something like {{replacement_variable_name}}.
Then instead of using String.Split(), you can use Regex to find all replacement variables and replace them with their actual values.
Here's an example
public string GetResultantString(string input)
{
    var tokens = Regex.Matches(input, @"{{[\w\s]+}}");
    return ReplaceTokens(input, tokens);
}

private string ReplaceTokens(string input, MatchCollection tokens)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Count; i++)
    {
        var token = tokens[i].Value;
        var tokenName = token.Replace("{{", "").Replace("}}", "");

        var tokenValue = GetTokenValue(device, tokenName);
        input = input.Replace(token, tokenValue);
    }

    return input;
}

private string GetTokenValue(string tokenName)
{
    switch(tokenName)
    {
        case "DamageTaken": //return the damage taken
        case "DamageDealt": //return the damage dealt
        ...and so on
    }
}

Then, your input string would be like player takes {{DamageTaken}} more damage and deals {{DamageDealt}} more damage.

actually it's not quite the correct approach. Localization is much better because it allows more complex transformation and also makes it easier to translate to other languages later. All good frameworks have built-in support for localization
